# Search and replace in C source code, without touching comments

Tags: c, regex, search

I have a lot of c code in which I would like to replace old syntax style with a new style. E.g. the following prefixes "si":

```
int siName;
```

should become "i":

```
int iName;
```

But the reg-expression or other find/replace tool, should not touch any source code comments.
Any solution?

Comment: (1) Some comments will reference the renamed variables and those should be fixed at the same time.  (2) What about string literals?  (3) This is non-trivial and will require a tool that understands C comments and strings and can do modestly clever regexes (you'll want to match only at the start of a word).

Comment: Eclipse CDT has a Refactor->Rename tool that will do this. Other IDEs probably have similar functionality.

Comment: If you are ok replacing comments as well, you can use this regex: `s/\bsi(?=\w+)/i/g`

Comment: No I have many different parameters with the same prefix. And I only like to change the prefix with one search replace command.

Comment: The Eclipse Refactor tool doesn't help there. And a reg exp which are also replacing comments, destroys the source code documentation. In this example all words which starts with si are destroyed. The situation is even worse, if it is tryed to do the opposite. Replace the prefix "i" with "si". There are many words which starts with "i".

Comment: A regex that doesn't replace comment references to function parameters is guaranteed to screw up documentation. (Good) refactoring tools ask if you want to include comments, and provide a list of what they are about to do.

Comment: If the prefix denotes the type there is a valuable lesson to be learnt.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/). It has a bit of a learning curve, but it parses the C code and executes the transformations given to it in a script. For example, for renaming a function from foo to bar, the script would look like this (from [here](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/coccinelle/docs/main_grammar011.html)):

```
@@

@@

-foo()
+bar()
```

It can probably rename variables based on regular expressions as well, I haven't yet found out a way though.

Answer (score 1):

In vi use

```
       :%s/\<Oldword\>/Newword/gc
```

This asks you whether or not to replace a particular occurrence of the whole word which you may happily neglect if it is a part of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the suggestion about Coccinelle, you can match using regular expressions using the following notation:

```
identifier foo =~ "xxx";
```

That is, foo will match any identifier that contains xxx.  PCRE regular expressions are supported.

You can also use python to create a new identifier:

```
@a@
identifier x;
@@

foo(x)

@script:python b@
x << a.x;
xx;
@@

coccinelle.xx = "%s%s" % (x,x)

@@
identifier a.x;
identifier b.xx;
@@

 foo(
-  x
+  xx
   )
```

For the program:

```
int main () {
  foo(one);
}
```

This gives

```
int main () {
  foo(oneone);
}
```